# Enumerate EC2 Autoscaling Instances in a ASG Group

Tags: terraform

I need to spin up to 5 instances in my ASG.
My code deployment and monitoring scripts make use of A-records from route53 :

So for each instance created by ASG:

1. I pass a tag for name of the instance
2. I pass a tag for CNAME
3. I insert CNAME and the associated IP into Route53

The problem I have now is that I need to have something like this for each instance:

Instance 1 : Name = test-myapp-server1,  CNAME test.my-app1.xyz.
Instance 2 : Name = test-myapp-server2,  CNAME test.my-app2.xyz.

And then when ASG triggers the third instance, I should be able to make use of index 3, 4 and 5.

Is this possible using Terraform?

Comment: It looks like you intend to use DNS round robin to avoid using an Elastic Load Balancer. Why not use an Elastic Load Balancer?

Comment: Thanks Barend. Am using ELB and I have managed to fix this using Lambda with a workaround. However I have run in to another problem. Working on the same at the moment.